# How to verify types from response?

Tags: rest-assured

I have to check json response if it contains needed types. What do I mean:

```
{
    "success": {
        "anonym_id": 11156,
        "has_empty_profile": false,
        "token": "4690e404-cfec-4918-b555-2f0d84675eee",
        "twins": [],
        "uid": 7380
    }
}
```

So I have to check that "anonym_id" is int(not a specific number like here 11156, but just int), "has_empty_profile" is boolean, "token" is string etc.
How to do that with rest assured?

Comment: what resposne u want? are u want response code

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is

```
JsonPath js1 = new JsonPath(new File(
                "Your Json I stored in a file"));

        assertTrue(js1.get("success.findAll {anonym_id -> anonym_id=11156}.has_empty_profile") instanceof Boolean);
        assertTrue(js1.get("success.findAll {anonym_id -> anonym_id=11156}.token") instanceof String);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I'll try this out and re after it